# differenct apk from the same code

Tags: android, maven

I have a large project, which contains a lot of maven sub module, with sub projects. My problem, that I would like to create a different application (beta version) for my testers, from the same codebase. If I rename the application package than, the roboguice can't bind my mobules, because it says: "Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"

I understand why this error comes, but can anyone tell me please who can I create a separate APK from the same codebase, with or without MAVEN ?

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just sign the apk with a different signature than that you use with the release apk? Use a debug signature. I think the package name can remain the same. Just sign with a debug certificate/signature.

Comment: What is the main goal? You want to be able to run several version on the same device ? Or just building different APKs at the same time ? Did you had a look on Maven classifier?